# Do not copy blocks of text from Wikipedia/etc into tag wikis/excerpts

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Do not copy text verbatim from Wikipedia or elsewhere into tag wikis and excerpts. Not even if you do so in a license-compliant way. Here is why:

1. Any idiot can type the name of an anime or whatever into Google or Wikipedia and find exactly the same thing.
2. See #1.

If you are in the suggested edits queue, you should know that there is a special rejection reason exclusively for edits to tag wikis:

> This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something [useful to this community *specifically*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/), and be sure to attribute the original author. See: [How to reference material written by others](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Please use this rejection reason liberally. Here's a protip to get you started: if you see Japanese characters, there's a 99% chance it's copied from Wikipedia. Frankly, if you see anybody editing a tag wiki (not an excerpt; an actual wiki body) at all, it behooves you to google the first sentence and see if it shows up on Wikipedia or MAL. Odds are, it will.

(What prompted this? Well, someone just went through and made a buttload of bad suggested edits to various tag wikis, and most of them got approved.)

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. I'll try to keep my eye out for the copied content. I started reverting/removing some of them as I find them.

Comment: with the japanese characters i am guilty of copying these from WIkipedia and follow Wikipedia's same format (Bold italic for the English title, italic for the romaji) but i think putting in the japanese title can be relevant for a series. i would suggest that if the first sentence appears in Wikipedia or MAL it's worth a minute of two to make sure how much of the rest of tag edit had been copied and paste. just the title and the Japanese name i'm willing to let slide

Comment: @Memor-X: Personally, I don't see any problem in just copying the names (Japanese and romaji). The problem is people just copy the plot descriptions and stuffs directly from Wikipedia.