# How do I make good Tag Wikis/Excerpts?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

After reading [this meta question](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2744/1587) I am wondering. how can i make a good Tag Wiki/Excerpt?

Comment: Related: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/937/

Answer (score 6):

## Series Tags

### Section 1 - Intro and Excerpt

The first section, generally 1 paragraph long, should contain the name of the series with any abbreviated name that's commonly used along with the original author. Other things that can also be added are the genre/demographic of the series (shounen, shoujo, mystery, shoujo ai) and the kanji/kana

#### Examples

*Puella Magi Madoka Magica*

> **Puella Magi Madoka Magica** (also 魔法少女まどか☆マギカ, Mahō Shōjo Madoka Magika) is an original anime from 2011 of the magical girl genre by animation studio SHAFT, directed by Shinbo Akiyuki and written by Urobuchi Gen. It is well known for its dark themes and references, unlike most traditional magical girl shows.

*Maria-sama ga Miteru*

> ***Maria-sama ga Miteru*** (マリア様がみてる, lit. "Maria Watches Over Us"), often shortened to *Marimite* (マリみて) is a light novel series by Oyuki Konno.

*Watamote*

> ***WataMote*** (*Watashi ga Motenai no wa dou Kangaete mo Omaera ga Warui!* / *No Matter How I Look at It, It's You Guys' Fault I'm Not Popular!*) is a manga series by Nico Tanigawa. A 12-episode anime adaptation aired in summer 2013.

This section can also be used for the tag excerpt however it's also handy (but not required) to add an extra line describing the story or if it received any adaptions

### Section 2 - Story

This section includes a brief of the story or the setting of the series. these can be a couple of paragraphs long however try and summarize it to about 2 paragraphs.

For series with a number of different and separate plots like with [atelier](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atelier) or [pretty-cure](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pretty-cure) it's best to describe how the different titles are connected.

#### Examples

*Maria-sama ga Miteru*

> The story is about a group of teenage girls attending the Catholic Lillian Girls' Academy in Tokyo, Japan, and focuses on the lives and close relationships of the school's student council, known as the Yamayuri Council. It is broken up into 3 families, Chinensis (Red Rose), Gigantea (Yellow Rose) and Foetida (White Rose), each headed by a senior Lady Rose (or *Rosa*). A Rosa has a junior student as their younger sister or *petite sœur* called an *en bouton* who in turn may have a younger sister of their own known as an *en bouton petite sœur*.
>
> Often the story is focused on the developing relationship of the Chinensis Family couple Sachiko Ogasawara and her en bouton (en bouton petite sœur in Season 1) Yumi Fukuzawa.

*Sono Hanabira*

> The series follows the the developing relationships of the featured couples, with each game usually focusing on one couple. The series centers around 2 locations:
>
> - Saint Michael’s School for Girls (in *Sono Hanabira ni Kuchizuke o*; *Hanahira!*)
> - Saint Michael’s General Hospital (in *Sono Hanabira ni Kuchizuke o - Tenshi*)

*Pretty Cure*

> The "Pretty Cures" are girls who can transform into magical girls with several different origins depending on the series.

### Section 3 - Release Information

This Section includes where a series has been release in what forms, this includes:

- What magazine it may have been serialized
- When it was adapted into another format (Light Novel => Manga, Manga =-> Anime, etc)
- What other spinoffs there are and their titles
- When which distributors (Funimation, Aniplex, Madman) got the license to distribute the media

dot points 1 and 2 generally can be merged into one paragraph while dot points 3 and 4 can be their own.

Dot point 3 can also be separated into separate paragraphs if the series contains sub series which can be considered different but do not have their own series tag. if a sub series does have it's own series tag then an extra line to mention this should also be included

#### Examples

*Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha*

> The series has 3 anime seasons, namely Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha, Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha A's, and Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS, as well as movies Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha: The Movie 1st and Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha: The Movie 2nd A's. There are manga adaptations of all of these, as well as several more manga series in the franchise such as *ViVid* which has seen an anime adaption and *Magical Record Lyrical Nanoha Force*.
>
> A New series titled *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha INNOCENT* set is an alternate continuity focuses on a motion based simulation card game. the players of this game are the original series characters like Nanoha and Fate but also characters from the PSP games like the Florian Family and the Material Girls. INNOCENT includes a number of separate Manga series and a web based card game

*Maria-sama ga Miteru*

> The light novels have been adapted into a manga and a 4-season anime (season 3 being a 5-episode OVA). A spinoff special called ***Maria-sama ni wa Naisho*** (マリア様にはないしょ。, lit. "Don't Tell Mother Maria") is a series of small humourous "outtakes" in a "chibi" style that often inflates key character traits such as Kanako's size or Sei's teasing of Yumi.

*Monogatari Series*

> The light novels recieved a number of anime adaptations.
>
> - The first one, based on the *Bakemonogatari* novel and animated by the studio Shaft, aired in summer 2009 and had 12 episodes followed by 3 bonus episodes.
> - The second one, based on *Nisemonogatari*, aired in winter 2012 and had 11 episodes.
> - The third one, based on *Nekomonogatari (Black)* aired on December 31, 2012.
> - The fourth one, an anime named *Monogatari Series Second Season* aired on July 6, 2013 and had 26 episodes. It based on several *Monogatari Series* Light Novel, which are *Nekomonogatari:White*, *Kabukimonogatari*, *Otorimonogatari*, *Onimonogatari*, and *Koimonogatari*.
> - The fifth one, based on *Hanamonogatari* have all of its five episodes aired on Augustus 6, 2014.
> - The Sixth one, based on *Tsukimonogatari* have all of its four episodes aired on December 31, 2014.
>
> Other media includes a drama CD, released on August 3, 2009; a PlayStation Portable visual novel titled Bakemonogatari Portable that was released on August 23, 2012; and a number of nendoroid figures.

### Section 4 - See Also

This is where you can list links which have more infromation and generally where you got the information for the above, places you can use may include

- Wikipedia
- My Anime List
- Anime News Network
- Visual Novel Database (for Visual Novels)
- Wikia's (like Type-Moon, Nanoha, Sword Art Online etc.)

For series like Pretty Cure or xxxHolic sites like Anime News Network will normally list all related series so you only really need to include one link rather than every subseries

### Extra - Image

alot of series tags contain an image (or sometime 2) at the top of the tag wiki. there is no rule to what kind of image so long as it follows the Content Policy of Stack Exchange and it is not fan art.

An easy way to find an image is to look for Book/Disk Case Covers or use the feature image found in the list above

## Tips

- you can copy stuff from Wikipedia and other sites like the format for the first paragraph however try and rephrase it in your own way.
- if you find you need to use `>` to quote a website then you probably need to work on the quote more to make it a bit more original

Comment: I also like to put a 1-phrase resume in the excerpt.

Comment: So, like, you can do all these things if you really want to, I guess, but I'm pretty sure that people almost never read the wikis for series tags. Your effort would probably be better spent elsewhere. Also, please refrain from adding kana/kanji to excerpts. Space is limited for excerpts, and Japanese text tends to take up a lot of space, while providing no real benefit.