# Can we have tag wikis for [blend-s] and [how-clumsy-you-are-miss-ueno]?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

Tags under review here:

> - [blend-s](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blend-s)
> - [how-clumsy-you-are-miss-ueno](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-clumsy-you-are-miss-ueno)

---

I am thinking of adding some descriptions for these tags.  The [blend-s](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blend-s) tag has been used in numerous posts (including my own) here, and [how-clumsy-you-are-miss-ueno](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-clumsy-you-are-miss-ueno) was only been used once (by me) so far.  Neither of them have their own tag wiki descriptions, and I would like to request the tag wikis for the two tags be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Tag descriptions for the two tags has been implemented:

> [image: Blend S tag wiki]
>
> [image: Ueno-san tag wiki]

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to propose these yourself, by hitting the "help us create it" link on the tag page:

[image: "The [tag:blend-s] tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it? "]

After you do so, your proposed edit will go to the suggested edits queue, where other members of the community can review it — and either reject, improve, or approve it.

Have a look at [How do I make good Tag Wikis/Excerpts?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2747/49), for some tips on how to write good tag wikis.

Comment: The tag excerpts has been implemented.  See the new accepted answer.