# Is there a meta post here on Anime.SE that explains user bans?

Tags: support

Is there a meta Question and answers regarding the topic about bans?

For example if a user is banned from doing something such as a privilege in this site.
Also like what he/he is prevented from doing, or how many days, months, years this is effective?
If a new User or an *Unexperienced* user does something that banned his/her account but can still login to the site, where could he/she find the explanation as to what happened and to also notify him/her of what NOT to do next time.

I've been searching the meta about *ban*, *user ban*, etc. Is it SE wide? or the rules here on Anime.SE different?

Thank You for answering.

Comment: From what I've seen, you've made a bunch of tag wiki/excerpt edit suggestions which have been many times rejected, showing that most of the time you don't know what you're doing with that privilege. One option to avoid such a situation is to consult with other users in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) about the edits you want to propose, before actually proposing them. This can help prevent rejected edits and wasted review time for others.

Comment: The [help center](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=ban) may help you !

Comment: @Hakase Sorry I should have asked someone before making the edits on tag wiki's.

Comment: As for tag wiki, don't populate it by copying content from elsewhere. You may provide the same information in your own words by paraphrasing.

Comment: @nhahtdh if said copied content is released under a copy-left licence (i.e. creative-commons and the like), i think a citation and a link is better than a paraphrase, unless the editor is a good writer. some text to sew-in between citations to make a presentable tag wiki, and its done. That is how I approached several tag wikis I did, and if my memory serves, none have been rejected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system restrictions are the same network-wide, and not particular to this site. From looking at your profile, it looks like [Hakase's comment above](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2749/is-there-a-meta-post-here-on-anime-se-that-explains-user-bans#comment6340_2749) got it right: you had a bunch of rejected suggested edits, which is why you ended up having that privilege blocked for 7 days. See [this post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/208518), and these other two it links to ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/208518) and [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78192/208518)).

As [Ikaros's comments suggests](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2749/is-there-a-meta-post-here-on-anime-se-that-explains-user-bans#comment6341_2749), [the help centre](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/) is where you can generally find information about the system mechanics and whatnot. [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) may also be of assistance, in particular [this FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/208518).

You can always do what you did and ask on Meta about why you aren't able to use a particular privilege, and what you can do to prevent facing similar situations in the future — however, you can also make it easier for those trying to help you, by actually mentioning what blocks and messages you are facing. The worst that could happen, is someone just closing your question and/or pointing you to some other place where it has been answered before.

With regards to the problem you're facing, in particular, please read through these two posts that your edit spree actually triggered:

- [Do not copy blocks of text from Wikipedia/etc into tag wikis/excerpts](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2744/49)
- [How do I make good Tag Wikis/Excepts?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2747/49)